# НЕ то(,) что некоторые.

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении?

**НЕ то(,) что некоторые.**

Comment: А можно дать этот пример в контексте?

Comment: Собственно,вот:
"Мы гуляем весь день и не сидим дома,не то(,)что некоторые."
Предложение,как видно,разговорного характера)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашла вот такую информацию на сайте [mirslovarei.com](http://mirslovarei.com):

**А Не То Что** *союз разг*.
 1. Употр. при присоединении однородного члена предложения при отрицательном сравнении его с другими однородными членами; *не как, не то что*. 2. Употр. при присоединении однородного члена или однородного предложения, подчеркивая важность последующей части высказывания; *не то что*.

Словом, запятая не нужна, поскольку "не то что" - это один союз.

Comment: Cпасибо за вразумительный ответ)